# dynamically loaded form using ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I consulted very many posts but could not find a solution to my problem.

I load a file (CrList.htm, with a form in it) into a div (CrTable) using ajax like this:

```
    //POST
    $.post ( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),           
            function(info) {

                    $("#editCourse").empty();
                    $("#editCourse").html(info.message);

                    reloadList();



                }, "json" );


            $("#myForm").submit( function() {
                return false;
            });



                  $(this).val("");                                                                             
    });
}

function reloadList() {
    $("#CrTable").load("CrList.htm"); //Load the content into the div
}
```

The form loads perfectly but when I click the submit buttons, also generated dynamically, nothing happens.

Here is the form:

```
<form name="CrEditForm" id="CrEditForm" action="" method="POST">
    <table id="RCRCoursesTable" style="corder-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0px;">



        <?php

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):

        if ($num&1) { 
            $myStyle="background-color:#CCCCCC;";
        }
        else
        {
            $myStyle="background-color:#FFFFFF;";
        }
            echo "<tr id=\"$num\" style=\" $myStyle \"><td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["course"]) . "</td>";
            echo "<td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["language"]) . "</td>";
            echo "<td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["date"]) . "</td>";
            echo "<td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["stime"]) . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["etime"]) . "</td>";     
            echo "<td style=\"padding:0px;\">" . htmlentities($row["roomorsection"]) . "</td>";

            $courseID=$row["courseid"];
            $num=$num+1;        
        ?>

        <td>

        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="action edit" data-id="<?php echo $courseID; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>            

            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="action delete" data-id="<?php echo $courseID; ?>" />

        </td>

        <?php
        echo "</tr>\n";
        endwhile;


        ?>

        </table>    
    </form>
```

Here is the code that executes on button click:

```
   var url = 'editCr.php';
    $(function() {
      $('.action').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');


        var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
        var tr_id = parent.attr('id');


        var action = $(this).hasClass('edit') ? 'edit' : 'delete';
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: {id: id, action: action, tr_id: tr_id},
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(result) {


        $("#ackUpdate").html('');
        $("#editCourse").html(result);


      }
    });
  });
});
```

I suspect it is because the form is not bound or integrated to the already loaded htm file but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Where is a submit button in that form?

Comment: It is the two buttons, edit and delete on the last tds of each row.

Comment: Yeah i saw that. Those are simple buttons . If it's a submit button type="submit" should be given.

Comment: This is how they are called $("#submit").click( function() { //then the post code above }

Comment: How will `$("#submit").click(` do anything when your button doesn't even have an `id` attribute, much less one with a value of `submit`?

Comment: I am sorry. I still don't get it . You want to submit CrEditForm right?
And you want this done by clicking edit or delete button , which you said is done by the script `$("#submit").click( function() { //then the post code above }`  , but those don't have id's!

Comment: I screwed-up. I just added the code I was missing for the button click. Has been a long day.

Answer (score 2):

The event is lost when you update the button over ajax.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.action', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio it worked! I am new to stackoverflow and I don't know how to turn the tick mark green.

Comment: I think you must have more than 15 points to accept the answer. If you ask good question your ratting will improve. Check here what you can and can't do: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges